# Subversion checkout from multiple repositories

Tags: svn

I am using windows and have to write a script to build a working copy of a dataset from multiple repositories.  Is there any simple way to script this and specify the directory I want that built copy to live in?

Comment: Are you asking for more than just a collection of `svn checkout` commands in a .bat file? That's the obvious method if you don't want to use svn:externals to store that WC layout right in your repository.

Comment: A better question would be how to consolidate your svn repositories.  Why fight with svn:externals or a script? if it's all one big lump of stuff, make the source layout reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).